# React MUI startCellEditMode function isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have a Datagrid in MUI in which each button has an edit button. I implemented the edit buttons in the actions of a column definition.

As I see in docs, MUI has a startCellEditMode function which could use as:

```
  const handleEditClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    apiRef.current.startCellEditMode({ id, field: 'text' });
  };
```

Now I want to use this line of code onClick of my edit button, but it doesn't work and I get this error:

```
apiRef.current.startCellEditMode is not a function
```

my function is called correctly, but the corresponding cell doesn't go to the edit mode

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Your data-grid, apiRef etc.

Comment: You can see the simple version here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-lake-c1f5c4?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: I think it can only be used with `DataGridPro`.

Comment: I have the pro version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to add this to your DataGrid component, I believe this works on the free version even.

As stated on the documentation: "Although it says "experimental," you can consider it stable." So, it should be good to go.

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/

<DataGrid
experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}

Comment: Thanks for helping! but kindly saying, this does not answer the question directly, the OP is using another method for this, and is going through the apiRef way, which is only available in the commercial version. Choosing the method of the solution depends on the senario we encounter.

Comment: This is for v5, its part of the default setup for v6

Comment: THANK YOU! How did you ever find this? The examples don't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an experimental feature in the premium version.

I solved it by adding the `apiRef={apiRef}` to the datagrid component. The docs were not so clear in this regard.
e.g.

```
import { useGridApiRef } from '@mui/x-data-grid-premium'
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef()
<DataGridPremium apiRef={apiRef} ....
```